# shell_exec throws: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: php, bash

I have been trying to execute a script using shell_exec() function in php:

I've written the following lines of code:

```
$command = "bash /path/to/my/script/ funciton_name() 2>&1";
echo shell_exec($command);
```

Inside the shell script I'm doing:

```
sudo rsync -avvc /source/path /destination/path
```

On executing this on the browser, I get the following error message:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

When I execute the same shell script on my server, it executes fine.

When I went through similar questions posted on this forum, I realised that I had to add the NOPASSWD line on my server which I found out has already been added in the following format:

```
User_Alias  NOBODY=nobody,apache
NOBODY  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD : /path/to/my/script
```

Also when I do:

```
echo shell_exec("whois");
```

I get the output as:

```
apache
```

Any assistance in overcoming this problem would be of great help.

Comment: A *far* better approach would be to give proper permissions on the path you're trying to rsync than to grant Apache and every other program running as "nobody" unfettered root access without a password. You're asking for your server to be compromised. Doing so would solve your tty problem as well.

Comment: @Cfreak - I tried changing the file permissions of the specific directory that I'm trying to rsync but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` *will* require a TTY, even if you have set up it up to be passwordless, unless you [explicitly do not require it](https://serverfault.com/a/111102/11292). But as [@Cfreak pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626681/shell-exec-throws-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified#comment43674037_27626681), it would be much better (simpler *and* [safer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65789/3645)) to avoid `sudo` by setting correct [access rights](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Permissions) (read it before continuing) in the first place.

`rsync` *itself* will not require root permissions on a sanely configured *nix install. To verify this, you can check that `type -a rsync` doesn't print anything weird like `` rsync is aliased to `sudo rsync' `` and that `ls -l $(which rsync)`  prints sensible permissions (at least `rx` for everyone).

Comment: I tried changing the permissions of both the source folder and destination folder by changing the owner and group to apache and setting the required permissions. But rsync on my server needs sudo access. Can you help in coming over this problem?